# Open Podfile is not working properly after installing multiple Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode8, xcode7.3, podfile

I am making podfile of my project but I have 2 xcode versions installed. like below image

[image]

One is xcode 8  and another is xcode 7.3

I also make my application open with default version xcode 7.3

[image]

but when I try to write `open -a Xcode2 Podfile` into terminal, Xcode 8 is opening for podfile. So what should I do for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just rename your Xcode 2 with Xcode_7 and try this:

```
open -a Xcode_7 Podfile
```